# Associative property not working for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is order of operations different when using mod? Example:

```
    //time[0] = '11', dif=4
    console.log( (time[0] - dif + 24) % 24 );           //prints 7
    console.log( (time[0] + 24 - dif) % 24 );           //prints 16
```

Comment: What is `time`?

Comment: If `time[0]` is a string, then things aren't going to work as you expect in the second statement. See what happens if you use `+time[0]` instead.

Comment: yep `1120 % 24` is 16. Your array has a string in it.

Comment: `parseInt(time[0])` does the trick

Comment: @GrafiCode — Don't use `parseInt` without a radix.

Comment: @GrafiCode as does `+time[0]`; `parseInt()` is kind-of problematic.

Comment: What's wrong with the unary operator or simply `Number`?